# How to get windows login username in asp.net with single sign on

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, single-sign-on

I want to get  windows login username in asp.net with single sign on

I use Global.asax Session_Start
I tried  WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
İt is working in local but it is not working in IIS. In local DomainName//UserName but in IIS IISAPPPOOL\AppName

In IIS Authenthentication => Anonymous Authenthentication is enabled, ASP.NET Impersonation is disabled, Forms Authentication is disabled also when ı change them application is not working.

```
My web config is like this
 <authentication mode="Windows">
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
<identity impersonate="true" />

Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name; is null
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name; is IIS IISAPPPOOL\AppName 
 Context.User.Identity.Name; is null
System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal p = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal; is null
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; is null
```

How can ı solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it :)
just Configuring IE Trusted Sites with Group Policy Preferences Registry
http://deployhappiness.com/managing-internet-explorer-trusted-sites-with-group-policy/
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just disable anonymous authentication and enable windows authentication.
Windows authentication may not be installed. If so, it will not work in any way. Go to server roles on Windows Server or windows features on Windows 7 / 8: [complete manual](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/providers/add).

Comment: thanks lorond I dit it. İt is working but now there is an Authentication Requred pop-up. I want to connect to page directly

Comment: @ErayDemirdir Is your browser is firefox?

Comment: yes in firefox there is an Authentication Requred pop-up. And in google chrome it is not working get error. I dont want to Authentication Requred pop-up please help me

Comment: @ErayDemirdir You should enable integrated authentication for your domain in these browsers. For example, look here: http://blogs.specopssoft.com/2014/06/configuring-chrome-and-firefox-for.html or just google by `firefox`, `chrome`, `ntlm`, `integrated authentication` and so on.

Comment: ı want to get user name with single sign on. I dont want to login panel or Authentication Requred pop-up

Comment: @ErayDemirdir to achieve such behavior with windows integrated authentication with firefox and chrome, these browsers need to be configured properly. See my previous comment. Also, client's PC must be in domain. Otherwise you be requested for login/password. If you want single sign on without windows integrated authentication, it's a complete different task.

Comment: thanks lorond. Our clients has a domain. So we dont want to requested for login/password. I want to login directly to application.Now we can get DoianName\UserName but after requested for login/password

Comment: @ErayDemirdir either configure browsers properly or user IE. By the way, does IE also requesting for login/pwd?

Comment: yes lorond all of browsers requesting for login/pwd